# Why doesn't C# allow a typeof as a default parameter?

Tags: c#, typeof, default-parameters

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(Type targetType = typeof(MyClass))
    {
    }
}
```

Isn't `typeof(MyClass)` a compile-time constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN - [Named and Optional Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

---

`typeof` does not necessarily return a compile time constant as it may return different results depending on context.

Comment: The type passed to `typeof` must be resolved at compile time. Hence I cannot see what you mean. If what you say is true, attributes should also disallow 'type constants'.

Comment: leppie, what you mean by "attributes should also disallow 'type constants'"? Where does attributes restrict values to be constants?

Comment: @Fujiy - Parameters passed in to attribute constructors need to be compile time constants.

Comment: Oded, the rule is: A Constant or typeof expression or a array creation

Answer (score 11):

I am not a IL expert, but seems that it calls a method at L_0005:

```
return typeof(int);
```

It´s the same of:

```
.maxstack 1
.locals init (
    [0] class [mscorlib]System.Type typeofvar)
L_0000: ldtoken int32
L_0005: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
L_000a: stloc.0 
L_000b: ldloc.0 
L_000c: ret
```

You can see that it isn´t a constant writing type of code:

```
const Type constType = typeof(int);
```

That returns a error:

```
Constant initialize must be compile-time constant
```

Comment: +1 nice way of answering his question and proving it isn't a compile time constant

Comment: The `RuntimeTypeHandle` is a constant, however.

Comment: RuntimeTypeHandle is a struct. Anyway, what is this change? RuntimeTypeHandle is just the argument of method call

Answer (score 4):

because it isn't necessarily a constant expression. your example features a typeof on a simple class but what if the class was generic? obviously this isn't constant by far:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
  public void MyMethod(Type targetType = typeof(MyClass<T>))
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: You might still expect it to be constant if you're used to generic types being done the way they are in C++, where each possible type `T` generates a new instance of the class.  That's not how it works in C# and .NET, so in C# `typeof(T)` can't be a compile-time constant, but in a template-based generic language it would be.

Answer (score 3):

This is old but if someone is looking for a Workaround:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod(Type targetType = null)
        {
            if(targetType == null)
            {
                targetType = typeof(MyClass);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't `typeof(MyClass)` a compile-time constant?

That *particular* expression is statically resolvable, yes, but `typeof()` is evaluated at execution time (because of generics), so the *rule* must be that a `typeof()` call isn't a compile-time constant.

I do wonder whether it *was* in C# 1.0, when there was no such argument to be made...

Comment: I don't think generics is the only reason for this. I think it's because this works: `typeof(ClassInExternalAssembly)`. It cannot be resolved until the actual external assembly is loaded, and therefore, it's not constant.